# Variables en CSS

Tags: css, web, diseño

Estoy en un proyecto y me ha salido el siguiente problema:

Tengo una caja grande que tiene 2 cajas más pequeñas en su interior. La caja grande tiene un `height` de `100%` y es `position:absolute`. Y de las 2 cajas que contiene, la primera no tiene un `height` especificado, ya que dependiendo de su contenido, será mayor o menor. El problema reside en que no se cuanto `height` le tengo que poner a la caja de abajo para que entre las dos ocupen el 100%.

He pensado que si se podría guardar el valor del `height` de la caja 1 en una variable, restarle ese valor al 100% e introducirlo en la caja 2, pero no encuentro nada que haga eso.

Dejo por aquí un JSfiddle para que os hagáis una idea de lo que quiero.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thj3vpum/1/)

```css
#todo{
  border: solid red 1px;
  
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  
  position:absolute;
}
#caja_1{
  border: solid green 1px;
  
  width : 100%;
  
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items:center;
}
#caja_2{
  border: solid orange 1px;
  
  width : 100%;
  height:50%;
  /*COMO PUEDO SABER ESTE HEIGHT PARA QUE OCUPE EL 100% DEL #TODO ENTRE LAS DOS CAJAS*/
  
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<div id="todo">
  <div id="caja_1">
    a
  </div>
  <div id="caja_2">
    b
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Podrías realizarlo mediante `display: grid`. Se trata de un sistema muy potente que nos permitiría, entre otras cosas, hacer que la fila **caja_1** ocupe lo que ocupa su contenido (auto) y la fila **caja_2** ocupe lo que falta para ocupar el 100% de altura de su padre (1fr).

```css
#todo{
  border: solid red 1px; 
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  position:absolute;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
}
#caja_1{
  border: solid green 1px; 
  width : 100%; 
}
#caja_2{
  border: solid orange 1px; 
  width : 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="todo">
  <div id="caja_1">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea</p>
  </div>
  <div id="caja_2">
    <p>B</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: muchísimas gracias por la ayuda, no había escuchado nunca sobre el display grid.

Answer (score 2):

Existen varias posibilidades. Una de ellas es volcar el Height en una variable, pero esto en css no es posible. Podrías recurrir a un framework de css de mas alto nivel que te lo permita como [SCSS](https://sass-lang.com/) que si permite la utilización de variables. (esto solo funcionaria si sabes de antemano el Height del elemento hijo antes de servir el contenido al cliente porque requiere que el css se compile..).

La otra posibilidad y a mi pensar creo la mejor, es que según el contenido y su correspondiente carga en el elemento padre manipular el height del elemento para que ajuste al de su padre con JQuery o Javascript.

Comment: Gracias por responder

Answer (score 2):

Con el método `.height` de `jQuery` puedes ayudarte.

*En el bloque de código `jQuery` encuentras la explicación en comentarios.*

```js
//Acá lo ejecuto cuando cargue el documento
//pero puedes usar el método que requieras
$(document).ready(function(){
  //Obtengo el valor de #todo y #caja_1
  var todo = $("#todo").height();
  var caja1 = $("#caja_1").height();
  console.log(todo, caja1)
  
  //A #caja_2 le asigno la altura de las variables todo - caja1
  $("#caja_2").height(todo - caja1);
  
  //Solo con fines demostrativos 
  var caja2 = $("#caja_2").height();
  console.log(caja2)
});
```

```css
#todo{
  border: solid red 1px;
  width: 80%;
  height: 300px;
  position:absolute;
}
#caja_1{
  border: solid green 1px;
  width : 100%;
  height: auto;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items:center;
}
#caja_2{
  border: solid orange 1px;
  width : 100%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="todo">
  <div id="caja_1">
    línea 1<br>línea 2<br>línea 3<br>
  </div>
  <div id="caja_2">
    b
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias por responder